# Template files not being discovered

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I was experiencing an odd problem where blocks were not showing up on a site. After a lot of spelunking I have found that block.tpl.php is not getting called/discovered.

Looking at the suggestions that the theme engine is trying to find it looks like the most general template it will look for is `block-MODULE.tpl.php` - ie if I set up symlinks for `block-block.tpl.php`, `block-views.tpl.php` etc then the content will show.
It just won't find `block.tpl.php`

So I can *kind of* make the problem go away, but I'd feel a lot better if I could fix it properly.

Anyone know why (or where) this would happen?

This is **drupal 6**, with a **zen** subtheme. zen is in `sites/all/themes/` the subtheme is in `sites/example.com/themes/`.

(it does seem to be finding `page.tpl`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had added a to the hook_theme() function in template.php for blocks that was pointing to a different location and confusing everyone.

Why I did that is lost to history, but it seems to server no useful purpose.

Comment: It feels real weird answering and accepting my answer like this, but it seems that 'Turns out I did something dumb' is not a reason to Close a question, and I can't delete it? Just 'vote' for it's deletion? 
Anyhow.

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue with zen and my sub-theme in Drupal 6.20 with the latest zen. It won't find the templates in the sub-theme's folder but it does find them if I move them into the zen/zen theme folder. The suggestions in $vars['template_files'] are correct, as I can see printing them in mytheme_preprocess_node(). So there's something else going on in my situation and this may be a more general issue. So might as well consider this not quite solved yet!

Answer (score 2):

PHPTemplate *will* find the more general templates (e.g. `block.tpl.php`): you can confirm this behavior by looking in the `themes/garland` folder which has its own `block.tpl.php`.

The most common reason for the template engine ignoring your template overrides is because the theme registry has not been reset. You can reset it by going to *Site Configuration* -> *Performance* and clicking *Clear cached data* at the bottom of the page.

Also make sure you've gone through and followed the instructions for sub-theming exactly: missing a step can produce unexpected results:

- [How to build your own sub-theme (6.x-2.x)](http://drupal.org/node/629510)
- [How to build your own sub-theme (6.x-1.x)](http://drupal.org/node/226507)

Comment: I have cleared the theme registry all sorts of times - and enabled  auto-rebuild-of-theme-registry-on-every-page-load with no difference.
I am pretty sure I have made the subtheme properly - everything works except this - and I can't see what step might cause it to skip 'block.tpl.php' but find 'block-block.tpl.php'

Answer (score 0):

there should be a version of block.tpl.php in both the theme and subtheme directories.